# Cannot find type definition file for 'highcharts'

Tags: highcharts, angular-cli, angular5

I followed the installation and example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts however, I get the error:

**ERROR in node_modules/angular-highcharts/chart.d.ts(1,23): error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'highcharts'.**

I'm working with angular-cli:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 9.3.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.41
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.10
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.10
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
...
import {ChartComponent} from "./chart/chart.component";
import {ChartModule} from "angular-highcharts";


@NgModule({
            declarations: [
              AppComponent,
              BatteryChargingDetailsComponent,
              ChartComponent
            ],
            imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              HttpClientModule,
              ChartModule,
              FormsModule,
              ReactiveFormsModule,
              MultiselectDropdownModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
            ],
            providers: [
              AuthService
            ],
            bootstrap: [AppComponent]
          })
export class AppModule {
  private static NgxAdminLteModule: any;
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "revolts-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:prod:pre": "rm -rf dist && node ./replace.build.js",
    "build:prod:auto-version": "npm version patch && npm run build:prod:pre",
    "build:prod:build": "ng build --prod",
    "build:prod:package": "cd dist && zip -r orcas-ui-$npm_package_version.zip .",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:prod:pre && npm run build:prod:build && npm run build:prod:package"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "admin-lte": "^2.4.2",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.6.3",
    "angular-admin-lte": "^0.2.5",
    "angular-auth0": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^5.2.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.4",
    "auth0-js": "^9.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

After googling a bit I found that some one has added  "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.12" to "dependencies" in package.json.
.. and after npm install 
ng serve -> no errors here.

on google console I get:

```
scripts.bundle.js:11 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16
    at Object.a.error (scripts.bundle.js:11)
    at eval (highcharts.js:8)
    at eval (highcharts.js:9)
    at eval (highcharts.js:8)
    at eval (highcharts.js:8)
    at Object.../../../../highcharts/highcharts.js (vendor.bundle.js:336)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (angular-highcharts.es5.js:8)
    at Object.../../../../angular-highcharts/angular-highcharts.es5.js (vendor.bundle.js:39)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
a.error @ scripts.bundle.js:11
(anonymous) @ highcharts.js:8
(anonymous) @ highcharts.js:9
(anonymous) @ highcharts.js:8
(anonymous) @ highcharts.js:8
```

where is my issue here?

Comment: found the Problem: I found in .angular-cli.json an old entry =>       "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js" ],. After delete thie entry, all is working fine.

Answer (score 19):

npm install --save @types/highcharts

Comment: Run (**sudo npm i -g npm**) to update your packages for compatibility issue resolving

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

> You Need to add typings to make it highcharts available , you can add by below commend :

```
npm install --save @types/highcharts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Following to you app.module

```
import {ChartModule} from "angular2-highcharts";
import {HighchartsStatic} from "angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService";
export function highchartsFactory() {
  var hc = require('highcharts');
  var hcm = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  var exp = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
  var drill = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');

  hcm(hc);
  exp(hc);
  drill(hc)
  return hc;
}
@NgModule({
..
providers: [
    {
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }
  ],
  })
```

[`Working Link`](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/charts)

*I had done this long back so if anything breaks please pardon me but it works with Angular pentagonal donut*

Comment: you work with angular2?.., I have angular5 and the module angular-highcharts not angular2-highcharts, as you can see in package.json.    "angular-highcharts": "^5.2.0", "highcharts": "^6.0.4",

Answer (score -1):

I commented out the top line of the file 'node_modules/angular-highcharts/chart.d.ts':

```
<reference type="highcharts">
```

This prevented the error and the Module seems to be working fine.

Comment: why would you do that? Next time there's an update, all your efforts would be overwritten. It is never a good idea to edit anything in the node_modules like @PascalC. pointed out

Comment: why would you do that? Next time there's an update, all your efforts would be overwritten. It is never a good idea to edit anything in the node_modules like @PascalC. pointed out