# zone.js:680 Unhandled Promise rejection: chartModule is not a function

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-cli

I am trying to import a module which uses highcarts and want to render the components in the module in my cli app.

But i am getting this error

I am using

```
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.16",
"angular": "^1.6.9",
"angular-highcharts": "^5.2.8",
"core-js": "~2.5.1",
"highcharts": "^6.0.6",
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

```
export class LineStatisticsComponent {
```

chart = new Chart({

```
title: {
    text: 'sample chart '
},
```

Comment: which chart are you trying to import ?

Comment: I am trying to display a column chart

Comment: you might want to look at this answer  might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48224622/2708210

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix by using

```
ng serve --target=production --aot=true
```

I am not sure why this is happening but with

```
ng serve
```

alone fails with error chart module is not a function
So if anyone has an insight why this behavior is there let me know